How to obtain the name of a bad QueryParam in the custom BadRequest message?
Consider this JAX-RS / RestEasy endpoint:
@GET
@Path("/my-endpoint")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response myEndpoint(@QueryParam("mySuperParam") @NotNull final MyParamType myParam) {
    return ok(myParam.toString());
} 

As you can see this is not a POST query. There is no Json payload. We get the param from the query, as a QueryParam. You can also see that I want to automatically convert the param to a custom type : MyParamType
// Simple wrapper around String. This is simplified for StackOverflow.
public record MyParamType(@Nullable String value) {
    public MyParamType {
        if(value == null)
            return;

        // Some custom validation
        if(!value.contains("-")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is missing -");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}

The conversion is done rather easily with a ParamConverter and its ParamConverterProvider :
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MyParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(
        final Class<T> rawType,
        final Type genericType,
        final Annotation[] annotations
    ) {
        if (rawType.isAssignableFrom(MyParamType.class)) {
            try {
                return (ParamConverter<T>) new MyParamConverter();
            } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // Here I DO have access to the QueryParam's name
                final @NotNull String paramName = /* extract "mySuperParam" from the annotations just above*/
                // POSSIBLE THROW LOCATION #1
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad param:" + paramName);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter;


public class MyParamConverter implements ParamConverter<MyParamType> {

    @Override
    public MyParamType fromString(final String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return new MyParamType(value);
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Here I do NOT have access to the param's name
            // POSSIBLE THROW LOCATION #2
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage()); // Rethrowing. Keep reading to know why.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable String toString(final @Nullable MyParamType value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return value.toString();
    }
}

Now I want to catch the IllegalArgumentExceptions and I want to convert them to BadRequest.
I start by writing an ExceptionMapper :
import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;


@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final BadRequestException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                       .entity("I wish I had the param name to show you!")
                       .build();
    }
}

As per documentation, RestEasy will only let me apply ExceptionMapper<> on an exception that is a WebApplicationException (For example, ExceptionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> gets ignored).
Nevermind then, all I have to do is to replace any of the two  throw new IllegalArgumentException(...) from above with  throw new BadRequestException(...).
Problem : none of the two locations is entirely satisfactory

If I throw a BadRequestException in "POSSIBLE THROW LOCATION #2" then its gets caught by the exception mapper but I do not have access to the parameter's name.
It's not possible to throw from "POSSIBLE THROW LOCATION #1" because RestEasy will never enter that catch block! Any exception thrown in POSSIBLE LOCATION #2 gets caught by RestEasy and converted to some HTTP Response.

What is the proper way of returning a custom HTTP400 message that contains the name of the faulty QueryParam after my custom validation threw an exception?
Note: I could pass the annotations to the constructor of MyParamConverter but my instinct tells me that there's a more standard solution that I'm missing.

There really isn't a way to get the parameter name in Jakarta REST or RESTEasy. The ParamConverter is catching the exception and throwing a new one. You've got two options.

Pass in the parameter name as you suggest into MyParamConverter.
Instead of using an IllegalArgumentException, create a new exception like ParameterViolationException which contains the parameter name.


I didn't know about ParameterViolationException! Excellent! I will try it.

ParameterViolationException is not a real exception, it doesn't exist :-(

Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant you could create a new exception that you throw which could be named something like ParameterViolationException where you'd have something like a getParameterName() method so you could get the parameter name.

It seems to be that this suggestion doesn't solve the problem, because as the question explains, of the two places where I can raise the exception, one HAS access to the parameter name but can never be caught (because of RestEasy inner workings) while the other CAN be caught but does not have access to the parameter name.

Using a constructor for MyParamConvert(String name) seems like the simplest option really.

yes that's the "cleanest" way on paper, but in practice that would force me to parse the annotations first every time even when no error occurs. I decided to pass the annotations and only try to parse them when the parsing fails.

True, you could just pass in the annotation array and only process it on an exception.
